# How to display matching string in a file and count of matching string in unix

Tags: unix, count, grep

I've tried as below

```
grep 'test' testdoc|wc -l
```

I am getting the count of matched string. but I need to get the count and print the matched Lines. Can any one help me out.

Answer (score 1):

with `awk`:

```
grep 'test' testdoc|awk 'END{print NR}1'
```

In `awk`, **1** always evaluates to true, it performs default operation `{print $0}` - prints the current line stored in `$0`

**NR** is the number of the current record/line and in **END block** (or on the last line of the file) is it the number of lines in the file.

**END** block executes after executing all the **awk** code. so this is the last **awk** code going to execute.

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped, you can accept (and upvote) my answer. ^_^

Comment: @tso : Could you please explain the part `awk 'END{print NR}1'` ?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
grep pattern file | tee >(wc -l)
```

`tee` prints all the lines `grep` found and then passes them also to a process that counts the lines. It's like a `T` joint in plumbing, where the water comes in one side and goes out two others - i.e. a splitter.

Note that this is called *"process substitution"* and is a `bash`-specific construct and there is no space between `>` and `(`.

---

You can also do it with `awk` like this:

```
awk '/pattern/{print;n++} END{print n+0}' file
```

That says... *"If the line matches `pattern`, print it and increment `n`. At the end, print `n` - after adding zero to ensure it is a number not an empty string if there were no matches."*

Comment: Thanks mark. But getting the following error. "Missing name for redirect"

Comment: Are you using `bash`? Did you out extra spaces in my command maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
grep 'test' testdoc|wc -l
```

counts the number of lines where your pattern occurs and it is equivalent to

```
grep -c 'test' testdoc
```

To take into account multiple matches per line, use the option `-o`

```
grep  -o 'test' testdoc|wc -l
```

To get both lines and count you could use `tee` outputting to a temporary file `f` and append to `f` the result of the second `grep`:

```
grep "test" testdoc |tee >(wc -l 1>&f)|grep -o "test"|wc -l 1>>f && cat f

# or to get both outputs in a line:
grep "test" testdoc |tee >(wc -l|tr '\n' ' ' 1>&f)|grep -o "test"|wc -l 1>>f && cat f
```

Here's another solution not using `grep` (since in some distributions the `-o` option is missing)

```
awk 'BEGIN{lCount=0;count=0}{c=gsub(/test/,"");count+=c;if(c)lCount+=1;}END{print(lCount,count)}' testdoc
```